# Run a role and supply params. Multiline?

Tags: ansible

I have a role that rarely I have to run with very different params. So I have a special yaml playbook, that is used to customize this role. 
yaml file with a role that is customized like this:

install_custom.yml:

```
hosts:
  - only_one_specific_host

roles:
    - { role: install, param1: val1, complex_param1: { inner_param: "inner_value" }, param2: val2, ... }
```

Imagine 10 params. It's a long line I'd like to split it into multiple lines. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
hosts: only_one_specific_host

roles:
    - role: install
      param1: val1
      complex_param1: 
        - inner_param: "inner_value"
        -  param2: val2
```